# C List Segmentation Fault

Tags: c, list, pointers

Hello guys i got a problem while running this code:
trying to run the printf in the comment i got a segfault, also without that i dont see my listed printed ad the function Stampa should do.
Probably i am missing something with pointers

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct nodo {     // double linked list
    int info;
    struct nodo *prec;
    struct nodo *succ;
};
typedef struct nodo nodo;

struct nodo *Crealista(void);     
void Stampa (struct nodo *nodo);

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    struct nodo *p;
    p = Crealista();
    // printf("%d",p->succ->info);
    Stampa(p);

    return 0;
}

// this funct should print the whole list
void Stampa (struct nodo *p) {
    while (p->succ != NULL ) {
        printf("Value  : %d \n", p->info);
        p = p->succ;
    }
}

// this funct should create list with n members and return a pointer to the first element
struct nodo *Crealista(void) {
    struct nodo *p, *primo, *back;
    int i, n;
    p = NULL;
    primo = NULL;
    back = NULL;
    printf("Numero di elementi: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    printf("inserisci %d numeri interi positivi: ", n);
    for (i=0; i<n; i++) {
        p = malloc(sizeof(struct nodo));
        scanf("%d", &p->info);
        p->prec = back;
        p->succ = NULL;
        back = p;
    }
    primo = p;
    while (primo->prec != NULL) { primo = primo->prec;}

    return(primo);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Stampa()

Let's look at what we want to do when we print the entire list:

1. If the current element is valid, then we want to print it.
2. Then, we want to iterate to the next element, and continue this loop.

That's not what your code does. Your code looks to see if the current element has a successor, and if it does, we print the current element's value.

That function should actually be:

```
void Stampa (struct nodo *p) {
    while (p != NULL ) {
        printf("Value: %d\n", p->info);
        p = p->succ;
    }
}
```

#### Crealista()

1. If you tell `Crealista()` to create a list of 0 elements, your final while loop will exhibit undefined behavior.
2. If you tell `Crealista()` to create a list of less than 2 elements, your commented `printf()` in `main()` will cause undefined behavior (if it was uncommented).

#### Doubly Linked Lists

You never update the value of `nodo->succ`. You only update the value of `nodo->prev`. Here's one example of how to do that:

```
if (p->prec)
    p->prec->succ = p;
```

#### Putting all of this together

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>

struct nodo {
    int info;
    struct nodo *prec;
    struct nodo *succ;
};
typedef struct nodo nodo;

struct nodo *Crealista(void);     
void Stampa (struct nodo *nodo);

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    struct nodo *p;
    p = Crealista();
    Stampa(p);
}

// Print the list
void Stampa (struct nodo *p) {
    while (p != NULL ) {
        printf("Value: %d \n", p->info);
        p = p->succ;
    }
}

// Create a list of n elements
struct nodo *Crealista(void) {
    int i, n;
    struct nodo *p = NULL;
    struct nodo *primo = NULL;
    struct nodo *back = NULL;

    printf("Numero di elementi: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    assert(n != 0);
    printf("inserisci %d numeri interi positivi: ", n);

    for (i=0; i<n; i++) {
        p = malloc(sizeof(struct nodo));
        scanf("%d", &p->info);
        p->prec = back;
        p->succ = NULL;
        if (p->prec)
            p->prec->succ = p;
        back = p;
    }

    primo = p;
    while (primo != NULL && primo->prec != NULL)
        primo = primo->prec;

    return primo;
}
```

#### Which when run...

```
Numero di elementi: 5
inserisci 5 numeri interi positivi: 1 2 3 4 5
Value: 1 
Value: 2 
Value: 3 
Value: 4 
Value: 5
```

Comment: Versions of this post seem to be everywhere. Why aren't people researching what libraries exist to achieve, where possible I use the type GList from library GObject. This logic traversing the list may have occurred, but all other issues are dealt with a simple #include

Answer (score 1):

The `printf()` call you have commented out will always exhibit undefined behavior when `p->succ` is `NULL`, as it will be when `p` points to the last (or only) element of the list.  In that case, although the behavior is formally "undefined", it is quite likely to manifest as a segmentation fault.

Comment: The same would apply if `p` were `NULL`, but it doesn't look like that will happen in your program as it is currently written.  Instead, your program would (probably) crash in function `Crealista()` if you attempted to provide a zero-element list.

Comment: the printf command was just a test the behaviour of the pointer

Comment: @MicheleBottini, your question title calls out the segfault associated with the `printf()` as the problem.  My apologies for overlooking the other aspect of your question, but it looks like Bill Lynch has already addressed it.

Answer (score 0):

In stampa add check

```
while(p!=NULL)
{
  printf("Value %d",p->info);
  p=p->succ;
}
```

You are probably accessing it when it is not allocated. Check it this way there is no problem if it reaches a null value also. And initial null value will not cause problem also(if used).

I have modified your code

```
// this funct should create list with n members and return a pointer to the first element
struct nodo *Crealista(void) {
    struct nodo *p, *primo, *back;
    int i, n;
    p = NULL;
    primo = NULL;
    back = NULL;
    printf("Numero di elementi: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    printf("inserisci %d numeri interi positivi: ", n);
    p = (struct nodo *)malloc(sizeof(struct nodo));
        scanf("%d", &p->info);
        p->prec = back;
        p->succ = NULL;

        back = p;
    for (i=1; i<n; i++) {
        p = (struct nodo *)malloc(sizeof(struct nodo));
        scanf("%d", &p->info);
        p->prec = back;
        p->prec->succ=p;
        p->succ = NULL;
        back = p;
    }
    primo = p;
    while (primo->prec != NULL) { primo = primo->prec;}

    return(primo);
}
```

You are not setting the succ pointer of previous node correctly. That is what causing you the problem. Check now.

Comment: @MicheleBottini.: Now along with previous change change createlist function as shown in my answer. It will give correct result.